Why isn't this inverter based amplifier amplifying?
I was studying about CMOS inverter an amplifier for analog applications instead of its more well known application as a switch for digital circuits. For the following inverter based circuit :
I think the small signal equivalent would be something like this :
(Assuming that the small signal output resistances of the PMOS and NMOS are too large i.e. neglecting channel length modulation)
It should have a gain of -2 and the gain should increase in proportion to the number of inverters connected in a parallel manner on the left side. But, for some reason when I give and input of 100mV at the capacitor C7 and measure output voltage across the 10k load,the output is attenuated.

This is the inverter itself : 
The size of the NMOS is 1u/150n and size of the PMOS is 4u/150n such that the switching voltage is around 0.9V for a supply of 1.8V.

EDIT #1:
After putting a 1 Mega-Ohm resistor in parallel to the first stage (the 2 inverters in parallel) and checking the frequency response, I found that the amplifier works best at around 2 GHz...but when I changed the input frequency to 2 GHz, the output is the same as input, not amplified 2 times as expected.



plotting graphs for the voltage on the two internal nodes may give some insight.

You need to bias the input into the steep region of the transfer curve.
Add 1M or (somethjing like that) from out to in (parallel with the first two inverters)

The output is still attenuated. I had tried that before posting the question. I will also include that screenshot in my question.

is see very short time steps are the inverters fast enough?

Yep that's the problem. I just figured out that the inverters work best around 2GHz from their frequency response. But even at 2 GHz where I get the max gain, the output is the same as the input. It doesn't amplify it to 2x. Is the small signal equivalent wrong ?
